# change the numbers in the 1st column

Tags: python, file

I know sed or awk can tackle this kind of problem more elegantly perhaps. But I went the python way, so the problem is that I would like to renumber the first column of my data file from 1 to #of lines in the file. Is that a good idea to read the file by readlines? For small files perhaps, but large files not I suppose. So here is what I came up as a first attempt, any comments are appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

try:
    infilename = sys.argv[1]; outfilename = sys.argv[2];
except:
    print "Usage is <script> inFile outFile"

ifile = open(infilename,'r')
ofile = open(outfilename, 'w')

lines = ifile.readlines();

i=1
for line in lines: 
    list = line.split();
    list[0] = i
    i += 1 
    for val in list:
        ofile.write("%d " % int(val))
    ofile.write('\n')
    del list

ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

Comment: Don't use semicolons to end statement, this is not required in Python and is generally considered bad practice (as statement are more elegantly finished by a line return).

Comment: @tokland, :S right, I should improve on that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the file to keep only the current line in memory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

try:
    # dont use ; !
    infilename = sys.argv[1]
    outfilename = sys.argv[2]
except:
    print "Usage is <script> inFile outFile"


# you could use `with` here if you have a Python 2.7
ifile = open(infilename,'r')
ofile = open(outfilename, 'w')

# no need to count yourself, enumerate does that
# plus when you iterate over a file you get lines too
for i, line in enumerate(ifile, start=1):
    # dont shadow builtins like `list`
    parts = line.split()
    parts[0] = i
    # join is the inverse function to split
    new_line = ' '.join("%d" % int(val) for val in parts)
    ofile.write(new_line + '\n')

ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

@Umut Tabak: `("%d" % int(val) for val in parts)` is a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), they are kind of like lazy lists. It gives the same items as the list comprehension `["%d" % int(val) for val in parts]` but without actually creating the list.

Btw, the for block can be written even shorter, but it's slightly different because it doesn't enforce that all lines are `int`s anymore:

```
for i, line in enumerate(ifile, start=1):
    parts = line.split()
    parts[0] = "%d" % i
    new_line = ' '.join(parts)
    ofile.write(new_line + '\n')
```

Comment: "%d" % int(val) for val in parts how is this interpretted? int(val) for val in parts is a list comprehension, I guess not?

Comment: This will split on all whitespace but joins with just one space. Although I guess that probably doesn't matter. Could also use a `csv.reader` for more flexibility if the file format is well-specified.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do the `readlines()` at all, and instead:

```
for line in ifile:
```

Also, avoid naming variables with the name `list`. Since `list()` is a built-in function, you're shadowing that name which is poor practice.

There is no need to `del` a local variable like you've done with `del list`; this is automatically taken care of by Python's garbage collector. (In CPython, the garbage collector is reference-counted and deterministic.)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(infilename,'r') as ifile:
    with open(outfilename, 'w') as ofile:
         for (nr, line) in enumerate(ifile):
             line = line.split()
             line[0] = nr
             line.append('\n')
             ofile.write(' '.join(line))
```

Comment: I think you need a `.split()` in there somewhere.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill thanks I mistaked first column with first character;)

Comment: what about without in-place statements? ofile.write(" ".join([nr]+line.split()[1:]))

Comment: but then you must use '+' on the lists which is bad;)

Comment: @virhilo, there's nothing wrong with using `+` to concatenate two strings. It's the fastest way to do it.

Comment: @aaronasterling what? it's worst way to do it, you should use .join to concatenate 2 strings and .extend to concatenate two lists

Comment: '+' creating another list? so is much less efficient

Comment: @virhilo. If you don't want to create another list, then `list1 += list1` is faster than `list1.extend(list2)` because it saves an attribute lookup and is easier to read. If you do want to create another list, then `newlist = list1 + list2` is faster than `newlist = list1[:]; newlist.extend(list2)` and is __much__ easier to read. But we were originally talking about strings. For __two__ strings, `+` is pretty much the best way to put them together and you've yet to give one reason why that's not the case.

Comment: list += list is the same as list.extend(list) but as you say saves an attribute lookup:P but he used list + list so he CREATED ANOTHER list:) and about strings:
"String concatenation is best done with ''.join(seq) which is an O(n) process. In contrast, using the '+' or '+=' operators can result in an O(n**2) process because new strings may be built for each intermediate step. The CPython 2.4 interpreter mitigates this issue somewhat; however, ''.join(seq) remains the best practice." from: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed

Comment: @virhilo, concatenating two strings doesn't lead to O(n^2) behavior. For much more than that, `join` is best. Try using `timeit` to veryify for yourself. `python -mtimeit "'a' + 'b'"` and `python -mtimeit 'join(('a', 'b'))`. Also, sometimes one wants a new list.

Comment: @virhilo sorry. Typos on the last one `python -mtimeit "''.join(('a', 'b'))"`

Comment: @aaronasterling yes for few short strings:) but look at this: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/317549/

Comment: @virhilo. Right but that's not what we're discussing. We're discussing concatenating *two* strings. That's the only claim I ever made. *two* strings. For two strings, `+` is faster. That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

try:
    ifile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
    ofile = open(sys.argv[2], 'w+')
except:
    print "Usage is <script> inFile outFile"
else:
    for i, line in enumerate(ifile, start=1):
        items = [str(i)] + line.split()[1:]
        ofile.write(' '.join(items) + '\n')

    ifile.close()
    ofile.close()
```

There are a few points I'd like to discuss with my answer.  The first is the try block, where I'm checking that I can open the files. If no filenames are input, or if either file isn't openable, you'll get the usage message. You could of course break this up: check for text, and return appropriately return usage, and try opening the files, and appropriately return file opening failed. Or, you could check for specific exceptions and return different messages.

Next, enumeration is a convenient way to have the interpreter keep track of the index. In the loop itself, I'm joining the enumeration index and a 'slice' of the read line (everything but the first item). I then join those with a space and write them with a newline.

This is clear and short.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to split the whole line, just split the first column:

```
for i,line in enumerate(ifile,1):
    first,remaining = line.split(' ',1)
    ofile.write("{0} {1}".format(i,remaining))
```

Also, your `except` needs to exit or the rest of the file will run anyway.